# How to set a background color in Geany for PHP scope different from the HTML scope?

Tags: php, html, ubuntu, editor, geany

Which is the easiest way to set a background color for PHP code in Geany 0.21 (Ubuntu 12.04) different from the background color of the HTML scope?

The default background color for all the code is white. I would want to have a light gray background color for PHP scope only.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the settings done filetypes.php and filetypes.html inside the .config/geany folder. This will change the colors for pure file like foo.html and baa.php, but not scope sensitive. So having HTML inside a PHP file will most likely not be effected.

Also please check manual for more details: http://www.geany.org/manual/#filetype-configuration